# I fail to send POST variables with JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, post

I am developing an Android application. I am using JSON to communicate with server. I have a weird problem.

I have a question list. To sync android question database with server; i send all questions one by one with JSON post method.After i send first question, i wait the "success=1" tag from JSON and i send the following question. Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO questions (question, username, askedDate, questionIDFromAndroid )
        VALUES ( :question, :username, :askedDate, :questionIDFromAndroid)";

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());



    $query_params = array(
        ':question' => $_POST['question'],
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':questionIDFromAndroid' => $_POST['questionID'],
        ':askedDate' => $date 
    );


    try {

        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = $ex->getMessage() ;
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["questionID"] = $_POST['questionID'];
    $response["question"] = $_POST['question'];
    $response["message"] = "Question Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);

    unset($_POST);
}
?>
```

Look under $query_params variable. There, i read $_POST variables and pass them into MySQL. Here i can set all values correctly. The problem is; when i try to pass $_POST variables into JSON, server sends to android app only first question's values.

I mean, assume that i send 5 questions to server.

MySQL results(Everything is true):

1. question: questionID: 1; question: "Question 1"
2. question: questionID: 2; question: "Question 2"
3. question: questionID: 3; question: "Question 3"
4. question: questionID: 4; question: "Question 4"
5. question: questionID: 5; question: "Question 5"

JSON results(i get only first POST's values):

1. question: questionID: 1; question: "Question 1"
2. question: questionID: 1; question: "Question 1"
3. question: questionID: 1; question: "Question 1"
4. question: questionID: 1; question: "Question 1"
5. question: questionID: 1; question: "Question 1"

So, i couldn't understand that why i can pass POST values to mySQL correctly but i can't echo them as JSON.

I didn't send android codes, because i am sure that android app sends values correctly, because i can see the expected values in mySQL.

What i tried:

-Before i use POST variables, i passed them to a local variable, and i tried to use this local variable for inserting mySQL and echo JSON(The result is same)

Comment: Maybe maybe its cache?

Comment: Where do you actually see the JSON results? In your app? You should show that code.

Comment: Yea, you need to be more clear. By sending questions 1 by 1, you mean you send a quest for this PHP script for each question? What do your 'MySQL results' mean? Are they the queries strings that PHP generated or did each query actually return a successful query result..

Comment: PHP code looks fine, post your android code that receives the JSON returned from the PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. As i said, i send questions one by one, i use iteration for each question and i send them. My "JSONParser" object was out of the iteration. It was at the begining of iteration class but not in the iteration method. So, for each iteration my app read the first instance of JSONParser object. After i moved this code `JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();` inside my iteration method, my problem was solved.